# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Device Group sending support in Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm struggling to find an answer on if Firebase Cloud Messaging supports sending notifications to Device Groups in the v1 HTTP API.

According to the [migration documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1), sending to device groups is supported.

> Caution: Any apps that use **device group messaging** must continue to use the legacy API for the management of device groups (creating, updating, etc.). The HTTP v1 can send messages to device groups, but does not support management.

The important part being *"HTTP v1 can send messages to device groups"*

I'm using the `firebase-admin-python` SDK, and when sending a single or set of batch messages I get a successful response, but the push notification does not send.

Is sending to device groups actually supported by the SDK in the same way that `firebase_admin.messaging.send` and `firebase_admin.messaging.send_all` are? The statement above leads me to believe that they are, but pushes aren't delivering (they do deliver when using the older legacy FCM API)

Comment: How did you try to send to a device group from the SDK? The API only accepts individual device tokens, topic names and condition strings.

Comment: I tried to use the `firebase_admin.messaging.send` function, with a notification key in the as the `to` parameter in the Message object. If the API only accepts device tokens, topic names and condition strings, I'm confused as to why the documentation states that device group sends are supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the `token` parameter. There's no sparameter named `to` on `Message`.

The documentation you're quoting is for the HTTP v1 API. And it might very well support sending to device groups -- although I haven't been able to find any examples to confirm that. But I know for sure that the SDKs (all expect the Node.js SDK) neither expose nor support any functionality for sending to device groups. Docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message outline all the different ways you can send a message using the Python SDK, and it makes no mention of sending to device groups. The `Message.token` parameter must be given an individual device registration token.

It is however rather strange that the FCM backend does not return an error when passing a device group key as the token. I'd recommend reporting a bug for that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `token` instead of `to` (was getting muddled between the legacy and v1 payloads).

Comment: According to [current docs for sending messages to device groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-device-groups), the only difference between sending a message to a device or group is what you put in the `token` field.